# in image fusion when I compute SSIM between any two images ? please replay me

Tags: image, visible, infrared, fusion

I use two images as input in order to produce one image that is more informative than two input images when compute SSIM or PSNR I ask between any two images. input images are infrared and visible images.

I compute between visible image and output image but value of SSIM is very high arrive 99.7 must be in range [-1,1] and PSNR is very low